# How to capture the request url of mp3 file on the audiobook website?

Tags: python, audio, python-requests, capture

website:

```
https://www.ting22.com/ting/659-2.html
```

I'd like to get some audiobooks from the website above. In other words, I want to download the MP3 files of the audiobook from `659-2.html` to `659-1724.html`.

By using *F12* tools, In *[Network]->[Media*], I can see the Request URL of MP3 file, But I don't know how to get the URL using a script.

Here are some specs of what I'm using:

- System: Windows 7 x64
- Python: 3.7.0

Update:

For example, by using F12 tool, I can see the file's url is "http://audio.xmcdn.com/group58/M03/8D/07/wKgLc1zNaabhA__WAEJyyPUT5k4509.mp3"

But I don't know how to get the URL of MP3 file  in code ? Rather than how to download the file.

which library should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

Well that would be a bit more complicated because requests packages won't return the .mp3 source, so you need to use Selenium. Here is a tested solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
import urllib3
import shutil
import os


if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/mp3_folder'):
    os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+'/mp3_folder')


def downloadFile(url=None):
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    c = urllib3.PoolManager()
    with c.request('GET', url, preload_content=False) as resp, open('mp3_folder/'+filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(resp, out_file)
    resp.release_conn()


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')  # download chromedriver from here and place it near the script: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/72.0.3626.7/chromedriver_win32.zip
for i in range(2, 1725):
    try:
        driver.get('https://www.ting22.com/ting/659-%s.html' % i)
        src = driver.find_element_by_id('mySource').get_attribute('src')
        downloadFile(src)
        print(src)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: For example,the mp3 file url is "http://audio.xmcdn.com/group58/M03/8D/07/wKgLc1zNaabhA__WAEJyyPUT5k4509.mp3"；I mean that I don't know how to get the url from  webpage  in code,rather than how to download the mp3 file.

Comment: That's so kind of you ~   And I find that when I click the [play] button ,I can find the   mp3 url in [elements] label, then I can get the audio.src from [elements].then I can download the audio.

Comment: i am running into the same problem but my url looks like that : https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/api/tts/newSynthesize?voice=en-US_OliviaV3Voice&id=e3ba0ce0-1c77-4f78-bf0c-e00f5be67b0c , the page has only the audio that i want but don't know how to download it, some help please